# Custom back press handler causes mem leak

Tags: android, leakcanary

have registered custom back press with handler onCreate in fragment. But leak canary tells there is memory leak when the fragment gets destroyed.
This is on back press implementation called on onCreate.
[Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nWBV.png)

onDestroy
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDJ8o.png)

Leak Canary log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvxcx.jpg)

I removed the registered event handler and set to null but leak canary still warns

Comment: It is saying Constraint Layout leak. Can you check if it is library leak or your app leak??

Comment: I don't think it's the app leak. Btw have you checked the onDestroy method?.